# Меняется владелец на apache на сервере VDS

Tags: apache, vds, isp

Есть у меня VDS-сервер, на нем стоит панель *ISPmanager*, также установлена *Joomla!*. Когда я ставлю что-то с самой *Joomla!*, то владельцем становится `apache`. Почему так? Помогите разобраться. Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Это не проблема, а стандартное поведение Apache.

Comment: @kff, я так понял моего юзера надо добавить  в группу data, или я неправ?

Comment: Юзера добавить в группу, в которую входит `apache` и вписать `umask 002` в `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас вероятно процессы Apache запущены из под пользователя Apache, а PHP подключен в качестве модуля, т.е. выполняется внутри процесса. Поэтому когда вы создаете файлы из PHP, то владельцем их становится пользователь Apache.

Лучше не бороться с этим, а включить в группу Apache того, пользователя из под которого нужен доступ к файлам. Права доступа же на файлы и папки настроить таким образом, чтобы к ним имели доступ пользователи из группы Apache: 0664 для файлов и 0775 для папок. Самый быстрый способ добиться этого установив umask равным 002.

Comment: а  как это сделать через панель ISP?